Error "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" on table insert query in MySQL
Pretty common error, and I thought it would be easy to solve, but in this case, unfortunately I couldn't figure it out.
Java project connected to MySQL, set up with Connector/J.
Error occurs when adding a property (registering an apartment):

Related files:
Database.java:
....other methods and connection stuff

/**
 * Adds a property into the property table in the database
 * @param address
 * @param quadrant
 * @param type
 * @param numBedrooms
 * @param numBathrooms
 * @param furnished
 * @param fees
 * @param status
 * @param landID
 * @param startD
 * @param endD
 */
public void addProperty(String address,String quadrant, String type, int numBedrooms, int numBathrooms, String furnished, double fees, String status, int landID, String startD, String endD){
    try {
        String query = "INSERT INTO property(Address, quadrant, Type, NoOfBedrooms, NoOfBathrooms, Furnished, Fees, FeesPaid, Status, Landlord_ID, StartDate, EndDate) ";
        query += "VALUES ('%s', '%s','%s', %d, %d, '%s', %f, 'No', 'Active', %d, '%s', '%s')";
        query = String.format(query, address, quadrant, type, numBedrooms, numBathrooms, furnished, fees, landID, startD, endD);
        try (Statement stmt = dbConnect.createStatement()) {
            stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

...other methods

RegisterController.java:
...other stuff

    //Add property 
    public void add(Property p) {
        db.initializeConnection();
        db.addProperty(p.getAddress(), p.getQuadarnt(), p.getType(), p.getNumOfBedrooms(), p.getNumOfBathrooms(), p.getFurnished(), 0, p.getPropertyStatus(), landLordID, "null", "null");
        db.close();
    }

    
    //Handle property registrations
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource().equals(createProp.getRegister()))
        {
            if(!createProp.getStreetNoInput().equals("") && !createProp.getStreetNameInput().equals("") && !createProp.getCityInput().equals("") && !createProp.getPostalCodeInput().equals(""))
            {;
                String address = createProp.getStreetNoInput() +", " + createProp.getStreetNameInput() +", " + createProp.getCityInput() + ", " + createProp.getPostalCodeInput();
                Property p = new Property(landLordID, address, createProp.getQuadrantInput(), createProp.getTypeInput(), createProp.getNoOfBedInput(), createProp.getNoOfBathInput(), createProp.getFurnishedInput(), null, "Suspended");
                this.add(p);
                createProp.showDialog();
                createProp.destroyFrame();
                landView.turnOn();
            }
            else{
                createProp.showErrorDialog();
            }
        }

}
}

Property.java:
public class Property {
    //Member varables for the class Property
    private int id;                     //Property ID
    private int landlordID;             //Landlord ID        
    private String address;             //Property Address
    private String type;                //Property type [Detattached, Attached, Town House, Apartment]
    private int numOfBedrooms;          //Number of Bedrooms
    private int numOfBathrooms;         //Number of Bathrooms
    private String furnished;           //Furnished: Yes or No
    private Fees propertyFees;          //Object of Fees for Property fees
    private String propertyStatus;      //Property Status [Active, Rented, Cancelled, Suspeneded]
    private String quadrant;            //Property Quadrant [NW, NE, SW, SE]
    private String rentDate;            //Property Start Rent Date
    private String startDate;           //Property Start Date when it becomes Active
    private String endDate;             //Property End Date when property is removed from the application

and what's weird that it works on my friend's PC, although everything is the same on both of us.

The exception information is enough; there is no need to attach the image here. Do you think the image gives more information?

strongly recommended to use PreparedStatement instead of building the query (concatenation or format), not only because of Little Bobby Tables (explained: https://bobby-tables.com/ ||| are you sure that %f is formatting as expected? maybe it is using a comma , instead of a decimal point . (print the query) - system default Locale is used for that formatting, your friend's PC could be setup to use . - that would also be solved by using a PreparedStatement

In Java is strongly recommended NOT to concatenate strings to assemble a query. Use PreparedStatements where each parameters is represented by a ?. As it is, your app is fully open to SQL Injection.

@user85421, TheImpaler, it solved the problem, thank you very much!

The error is basically that when you made the String query the number of arguments that you provided in the query did not equal the number of arguments of the table in the database, check what arguments you are missing, check if the query works in the workbench, then write it in java.
also always use PreparedStatement, it is much easier to use and more organized, for example:
PreparedStatement myStmt; 
myStmt = myCon.prepareStatement(select * from students where age> ? and name = ?);
myStmt.setInt(1,10);    
myStmt.setString(2,"Chhavi"); 

